# QTreeView or QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, design-patterns, treeview, qtreewidget, model-view

I want to implement in my program a tree with nested sub-levels, and I'm looking for which of those two kind(View/Widget) is best suited for my goal.

I have a list of days with task that are either done/missed/failed, each task has a count of how many times it was done/missed/failed and lastly a score for that day.

I want to display them like so:

[image: tree display]

I made this example in QtCreator using a QTreeWidget, but I'm worried that it would be hard to modify the elements since they are stored somewhere else.

Are my worries rational and should I go to the model/view structure, or can I easily get going with the QTreeWidget? The tree will be logging the task and thus will be constantly changing. Elements will only be added to it, not removed. And the days will be sorted from highest-lowest(day 2 is first, then day 1)

Comment: Thanks, I had this same fuckin question!  You beat me by 8 years though!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your data is stored in a database model or if you want to have a single data model and show it in some views in different ways, then you are definitely better to go with `QTreeView`.

But `QTreeWidget` has it's internal model in some way along with the methods to deal with model in context of indexes. In general if you just want something that is simple to work, you can use the widget way.

But the Model/View approach is more general and flexible IMO. You can create your own subclasses of model and view which enables you to do whatever you like.