# I have a GUI, but not sure which Qt class to display it

Tags: qt, qwidget

[image]

Can anyone give me a hint which Qt GUI class best fit for this design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QTreeView or QTreeWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832814/qtreeview-or-qtreewidget)